# How to mock generic method with delegate parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

In a abstract class I have a virtual method with this signature.

```
public virtual async Task<TResult> MethodAsync<TParameters, TResult>(
        CommandFactory<TParameters> commandFactory,
        TParameters parameters,
        ModelAdapter<TResult> modelAdapter)
    { // method body }
```

`CommandFactory` and `ModelAdapter` are delegates with this signature.

```
public delegate DbCommand CommandFactory<in TParameters>(
    DbConnection connection,
    TParameters parameters);

public delegate TResult ModelAdapter<out TResult>(DbDataReader dataReader);
```

How to mock `MethodAsync` using `Moq`

Comment: Include the context under which it is used as well as an example of a test where you tried to mock it and what errors it gave

Answer (score 1):

It can be setup like any other virtual or abstract member

```
var mock = new Mock<MyAbstractClass>();
string expectedResult = "Hello World";
mock
    .Setup(_ => 
        _.MethodAsync(
            It.IsAny<CommandFactory<string>>(),
            It.IsAny<string>(),
            It.IsAny<ModelAdapter<string>>())
        )
    .ReturnsAsync(expectedResult);
```

The above example is simplifies to use strings just to demonstrate how the generic parameters are used.

`It.IsAny` argument matcher was used to setup the expectations for the parameters of the method

Comment: Thank you. I have used 'object' type to continue my work. I am looking for more generic way. Is it not possible to 'Setup' with generic parameters instead of 'string'? After searching more I think its not possible in generic way. Am I right?